# Beginners guide to learn how to use Subversion with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, version-control

What's the best way for me to learn how to use Subversion as a source code control for my Asp.Net Web Projects?

I haven't had much contact with source control before; however I have a very basic understanding of its features, so I'm looking for a way to learn the best practices.

Any tip will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you've [setup SVN](http://blogs.vertigosoftware.com/teamsystem/archive/2006/01/16/Setting_up_a_Subversion_Server_under_Windows.aspx) you'll need to setup your repository structure. A common setup is to have a [Branch, Tag, Trunk setup](http://ariejan.net/2006/11/24/svn-how-to-structure-your-repository/) however there are others that may suit your needs.

Once you've setup your server you'll need a client. The most common one is [TortoiseSVN.](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) It doesn't integrate with Visual Studio, however it's extremely powerful.

Once you install tortoise, you'll want to setup your [exclusion list](http://weblogs.asp.net/rchartier/archive/2005/10/17/427727.aspx) to make sure you only commit files that are relevant to your project.

Then for a better understanding of how to use source control in general check out Eric Sinks [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html)

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend VisualSVN. It is a great product for integrating Subversion with Visual Studio.

http://www.visualsvn.com/

Comment: I think that one should learn how to walk before he should run. One should learn TortoiseSVN first, then Visual SVN only after mastery of that.

Answer (score 2):

[TortoiseSVN?](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Pretty easy to use...

It's integrated into the windows shell so basically it works from Windows Explorer.. I'm not sure if its integrated into VisualStudio 2008, but it's so easy to use anyway that I dont think you'd need it.. :)

EDIT: Plus, it's free.. :) And it's got a bunch of tools like Diff/Merge.. :) Although for that I think WinMerge is better.. But that's beside the point.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) for integrating with visual studio. I works nicely and looks similar to TFS.  I also use tortoise svn for windows shell integration.  Both complement each other nicely.

Comment: I have installed it. Nothing else. Now how can I create a repository?

Comment: You installed ahkhsvn?  If thats all you installed you it just integrates with visual studio.  You still need to install subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly related to Subversion, but Eric Sink has an [excellent source control primer](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) if you need to review the basics. Don't forget that the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is free, and it's probably the most complete (and yet still quite practical) resource on Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Like Web and Jerry, I generally like AnkhSvn for Visual Studio integration, and also make use of TortoiseSvn as a complementary tool. (For example, Tortoise's log viewer is still a bit more advanced, so sometimes I'll go in with that.)

That said, I'm not totally sure I would suggest using AnkhSvn for ASP.NET Web Site Projects. (I use it for ASP.NET Web *Application* Projects, Class Library Projects, and Console Applications.) There are some quirks that you might find frustrating. See this message in particular and this thread in general, from the AnkhSvn mailing list:

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=132185

You could probably live with the quirks, and maybe the AnkhSvn will eventually eliminate them all, but in my case I chose to move to Web Application Projects (instead of Web Site Projects) partly because they work better with AnkhSvn.

Also, if you do go with AnkhSvn, I suggest running one of the nightly builds, rather than the latest stable release; the nightly builds seem to have many fewer bugs and to be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get any answers when i was getting my first svn set-up for php development... so i would like to help you but i dont know any visual studio integration.

I used tortoise(btw is great and is for windows, i could help you im sure) and theres a couple of [tutorials](https://www.projects.dev2dev.bea.com/Subversion%20Clients/TortoiseSVN.html) on how to set up a small repo in your own pc

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with source control terms and concepts first. Eric Sink has [written a great guide](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) for getting up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

I know someone has already said "AnkhSVN", but I'd like to second that nomination. I use AnkhSVN for my department, and I love it. It integrates completely with VS2008, and gives me almost no trouble.

I also use TortiseSVN for its "Repo Browser" functionality... but I rarely ever have to go into that anymore.

Both are EXCELLENT solutions, and used jointly, should be all you need. And both are free.